# Objective C: Create custom a type value for variable assignment

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a value that can be called from a data source, this value will determine what another variable receives. That sounds confusing, but basically I want my variable to be set to either of the following values (depending on what the data source says):

```
variable = variableValue/2;
```

or

```
variabel = 0;
```

variableValue is a property that can be changed dynamically. Anyway how can I use a boolean or int value coming from my data source to select either one of the options above. Do I make an enum?

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but it's escaping me. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question completely but can't you check that with an if construction?

```
bool test = YES;

if(test == YES)
{
    // select 1
}
else
{
    // select 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that would work great. Only problem is I have several instances of this value that needs to be assigned. So it would be cleaner if it were like an array and I chose either value from the array by index.

Comment: dictionary will be better than array.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a constant value, then use a constant.

```
#define kVariableValue           123
```

or

```
static int variableValue = 123;
```